# How to handle multiple listeners inside GridView in Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-gridview

In my app, a `GridView` has list of contents. Each item is inflated with a layout. Single item inside the gridview contains, an  image and 2 `textviews`.

I have a requirement that when I click on the image, the image should be replaced with another image and when I click on any other places it should open a popup. I am able to listen to the second event, using `OnItemClickListener`. It opens the popup. How can I handle the first case? I mean how can I listen to `OnClick` event of image?

Comment: set an `OnClickClistener` for the image.. you could even set up a switch statement in your listener to decide what to do if the image is clicked and a default condition. what have you tried so far?

Comment: @mango The below answer worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view adapter, when you set the image resource, also set an onClickListener for the  ImageView.

In my case, holder is a temporary static class which holds 2 TextViews and an ImageView.:

```
holder.mThumbnailImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.list.thumb);
holder.mThumbnailImageView.setImageResource(thisOrder.getIconValue());
holder.mThumbnailImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "image clicked: " + view.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I will check it and let you know