# Change color of imageview in custom gridview child item when clicked on another child item

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have a custom gridview.

In that, am using a frame layout which contains a image button, textview and a view. I need to change the background color of imageview/ text color of textview and drawable of view when an item is pressed.

In order to achieve that, I performed `setOnClickListener` inside that adapter. And to undo the changes i implemented `setOnLongClickListener`.

Now the question is, I want to change background color and all for only one item at a time. How do I achieve that? If item1 was selected previouslt,it should be unselected when I click on item2.

Let's say I store the position of item which has been clicked, how do I perform `setOnLongClickListener` for the item on that position when another item is clicked?

```
Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4
 Y       N       N       N

Position :0

Now after clicking on Item2,

Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4
 N       Y       N       N

I need to perform onlongClicklistener for that position.
```

Comment: I faced same problem and I searched this answer try this answer [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13880851/2774275)

Comment: The link talks about the onClick event for things inside a childitem. That's am doing anyway. I need to perform onLongClick for a item at a position which is known to me when I click on another item.

Answer (score 0):

I searched another answer for you but it is in list view you can change yourself to grid view 
[see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18549314/2774275)

Comment: If I perform onClick event for the image button in the adapter, am able to change the background color. So everytime I press a item, the color is being changed so multiple items are being selected and that is exactly which I don't want. I want the color of item to be reverted back to original when I click on another item.